# Ruby not working on windows xp

Tags: ruby, windows

I just installed ruby on windows xp 32bit with rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p645. The installation went smoothly with no errors. I made sure to check the box that added ruby to the windows path. Here is my path:

```
PATH=C:\Ruby200\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
```

However, ruby does nothing at the prompt. No error message, nothing. If I go to the bin directory of the Ruby installation folder and type ruby -v for example, nothing. The prompt just returns. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Here is the Ruby folder after install:

```
Directory of C:\Ruby200\bin

05/03/2015  02:17 PM    <DIR>          .
05/03/2015  02:17 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/14/2015  06:54 PM             4,397 erb
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               177 erb.bat
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               546 gem
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               177 gem.bat
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               318 irb
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               177 irb.bat
04/14/2015  06:54 PM         1,586,688 libeay32.dll
04/14/2015  06:54 PM           127,316 libffi-6.dll
04/14/2015  06:54 PM           140,586 libgdbm-3.dll
04/14/2015  06:54 PM           103,726 libgdbm_compat-3.dll
04/14/2015  06:54 PM         1,262,898 libiconv-2.dll
04/14/2015  06:54 PM           442,898 libyaml-0-2.dll
04/14/2015  06:41 PM         2,404,352 msvcrt-ruby200.dll
04/14/2015  06:54 PM           238,505 pdcurses.dll
04/14/2015  06:54 PM             1,320 rake
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               177 rake.bat
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               938 rdoc
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               177 rdoc.bat
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               188 ri
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               177 ri.bat
04/14/2015  06:41 PM           123,814 ruby.exe
04/14/2015  06:41 PM           123,814 rubyw.exe
02/13/2015  08:06 PM               312 setrbvars.bat
04/14/2015  06:54 PM           386,048 ssleay32.dll
04/14/2015  06:54 PM                78 testrb
04/14/2015  06:54 PM               177 testrb.bat
04/14/2015  06:54 PM            91,648 zlib1.dll
          27 File(s)      7,041,629 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  77,242,834,944 bytes free
```

Comment: are you sure it's not `ruby.exe` on windows? What's the contents of the ruby bin folder?

Comment: @MartinKonecny You don't have to type the extension of executable binaries.

Comment: I am going to reinstall for the third time, after that its nitrous.io

Comment: Even if you get this fixed, you may eventually have issues with Ruby and Windows, since few people learn Ruby without the final goal being Ruby on Rails. There is a nightmare to come with gems expecting the `/` for the file system vs Windows using the `\\` for the file system. I've heard awesome stuff about cloud9 (www.c9.io) being a good dev environment for Windows users.

Comment: Not necessarily related, but why Ruby 2.0? Why not 2.1.5 (or current version)?